# При запуске Android Studio, процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом

Tags: android, android-studio

При запуске Android Studio 1.5.1 проекта выдает

> Error: C\Document and Setting\Hel.gradle\daemon\2.8\registry.bin (Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом)

Раньше удаление registry и registry.bin.lock помогало. А теперь нет. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin не ограничивайтесь простым выпиливанием приветствий. Старайтесь и в остальном приводить вопрос в порядок (см. правку)